# How do I find the position of the max value in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have

```
ary = [7, 8, 0, 1, nil, 6]
```

How do I find the position of the max value in the array?  I can do this but it would take more than one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This returns the index of the first max value in the array:

```
ary = [7, 8, 0, 1, nil, 6, 8]
ary.index(ary.compact.max)
=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more verbose than the selected answer, but with only one traversal of the array and no intermediate arrays (assigns arbitrary `-1` as the sorting value for `nil`):

```
>> ary.each_with_index.max_by { |x, idx| x || -1 }[1] 
=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
ary.sort
ary.reverse
ary[0]
```

Comment: The question is looking for the position, not the max value itself. `ary.max` is an easier way to find the max value, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ary = [7, 8, 0, 1, nil, 6]
puts ary.index(ary.compact.max)
```

Comment: Good catch! Changed my answer to the same as every1 else :]